# AG-grid export to excel with group count

Tags: export, ag-grid

When exporting a grid with groups which have group count with it. The exported excel doesn't contain the group count. Is there a way to export with the group count?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by modifying the group header content in [`processRowGroupCallback`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-excel/#example-styling-row-groups). [Here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/#reference-properties) is all of the export options for reference.

```js
gridApi.exportDataAsExcel({
  processRowGroupCallback: (params) => {
    const { node } = params;
    return `${node.key} (${node.allChildrenCount})`;
  }
});
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit 64085383/ag-grid-export-to-excel-with-group-count/64086323#64086323]